# iCal & me.com file error (Snow Leopard)

Tags: snow-leopard, ical

Every day I get a couple of error messages on my Mac Pro iCal, presumably from Me.com, saying that I have a calendar file waiting. I click on OK, and then I always get another message, saying that iCal cannot read the file. It doesn't seem to have an effect on my calendar, but it is annoying to have to go through this every day. Any ideas on what I could check?

---

[image: First this appears:]

[image: then this appears:]

Comment: I'm going to close this as too localized since we are in the waning days of MobileMe - but feel free to comment or edit/flag this if you legitimately still have this issue and haven't migrated to iCloud already.